# Error Running Following code in C

Tags: c

I am a novice programmer and I encountered an error while running the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    int num=8,a=pow(10,num);
    printf("\n%d",a);
}
```

When I run this code, for even values of `num` I get a value which differs by 1. I ran this in `CODE::BLOCKS` with the GNU GCC compiler.
The following is a grab of my output screen.

output screen:
[image]

Comment: numeric precision: the topic that keeps on giving....

Comment: Why are you assigning the return value of pow(), which is a double, to an int?   Why are you showing us code with num=8, which is obviously not what you ran to get that screen dump?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link:
http://linux.die.net/man/3/pow

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    int num=8;
    double a=pow(10,num);/* return type of pow() is double not int */
    printf("\n%f",a);
}
```